# How to add path for flutter permanently in .bash_profile?

Tags: flutter, path

Hai I want to add path for flutter in .bash_profile.
1) I installed flutter and unzipped to my folder
2)Tried to add path in .bash_profile 
       export PATH="/myflutterflolder/flutter/bin:$PATH"
     I added and saved.
But When I run `flutter` command in terminal it is not showing.But I can set it temporarily.It is working fine.But Why I can't set it Permanantly.I am using macOS Catalia.Anyone Please help me.

Comment: what you see if you type: `echo $PATH`?

Comment: flutter path also is there when I type that command